# Loop through multiple form input variables in php

Tags: php, ajax

When I loop through Rice form variables at php end. everything work well.

```
<input class="rice" type="text" name="rice[]" >
<input class="beans" type="text" name="beans[]" >
<input class="price" type="text" name="price[]" >

// pdo connection
foreach($_POST['rice'] as $index => $value) {
$statement= $db->prepare('INSERT INTO product(rice)values(:rice)');

$statement->execute(array(':rice' => $value));

}
```

now how do I loop through beans and price as well
and then insert the three products, rice, beans and price into database.

```
// pdo connection
foreach($_POST['rice'] as $index => $value) {
$statement= $db->prepare('INSERT INTO product(rice,beans,price)values(:rice,:beans,:price)');

$statement->execute(array(':rice' => $value,':beans'=>$value2,':price'=>$value3));

}
```

Comment: that will mean inserting them in different rows in the database. and i don't want that

Comment: Any reason you're passing them as arrays within the form? Why not just `name="rice">` ... `name="beans">` ... `name="price">`? Then your query is very simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could loop through them like this:

```
// Make sure we have same amount of everything
$riceTotal = count($_POST['rice']);
if($riceTotal  == count($_POST['beans']) && $riceTotal == count($_POST['price']){
    foreach($_POST['rice'] as $key => $value){
        $statement = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO product(rice, beans, price) VALUES(:rice, :beans, :price)');

        $statement->execute(array(':rice' => $value, ':beans' => $_POST['beans'][$key], ':price' => $_POST['price'][$key]));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$arrayRBP = array('rice','beans','price');
foreach($arrayRBP as $data) {
    foreach($postArray as $value) {
       var_dump(${$value}[$data]);
    }
}
```